# Sumar el value de varios select en una tabla con php

Tags: php, jquery, html5

Tengo la siguiente tabla:

[image: Tabla]
Con el siguiente código:

```
    <table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th> Lunes </th>
            <th> Martes </th>
            <th> Miercoles </th>
            <th> Jueves </th>
            <th> Viernes </th>
            <th> Puntos Obtenidos </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <?php for ($i=1; $i <= 5 ; $i++):?>
            <td>
                <select name="puntos" id="puntos" required>
                <option value=""></option>
                <option value='12'>Verde</option>
                <option value='8'>Azul</option>
                <option value='6'>Amarillo</option>
                <option value='0'>Rojo</option>
                <option value='-8'>Negro</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <?php endfor;?>
        <td>
            <!-- Aquí iría el código para calcular los puntos -->
        </td>                           
    </tr>                       
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Necesito que en la última columna "**Puntos Obtenidos**" se muestre la suma de los puntos según los **option value** seleccionados en cada celda.

Intenté con Jquery pero sólo almacena el value de la primera celda.

```
<script>
    $("#puntos").change(function(){
        var valor = $(this).val();
        console.log(valor);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Si los datos vienen de PHP, como parece ser, me pregunto por qué no sumas los valores y los traes dentro de alguna clave de tu array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo puedes hacer de esta forma, aunque si son multiples filas deberia considerar ponerle id a cada fila para que el selector de la función solo sume los de su fila. Además, en tu código siempre repites el mismo id y eso es incorrecto:

```js
$("select").change(function(){
 var i=0;
   $(this).closest("tr").find("select").each(function(){
    if ( $(this).val() !== "" )
    i += parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
   });
   $(this).closest("tr").find(".res").val(i);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th> Lunes </th>
            <th> Martes </th>
            <th> Miercoles </th>
            <th> Puntos Obtenidos </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <select name="puntos" id="puntos" required>
                <option value=""></option>
                <option value='12'>Verde</option>
                <option value='8'>Azul</option>
                <option value='6'>Amarillo</option>
                <option value='0'>Rojo</option>
                <option value='-8'>Negro</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select name="puntos" id="puntos" required>
                <option value=""></option>
                <option value='12'>Verde</option>
                <option value='8'>Azul</option>
                <option value='6'>Amarillo</option>
                <option value='0'>Rojo</option>
                <option value='-8'>Negro</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select name="puntos" id="puntos" required>
                <option value=""></option>
                <option value='12'>Verde</option>
                <option value='8'>Azul</option>
                <option value='6'>Amarillo</option>
                <option value='0'>Rojo</option>
                <option value='-8'>Negro</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
            <input name="res" class="res" value=''>
            </td>                           
    </tr>                       
        <tr>
            <td>
                <select name="puntos" id="puntos" required>
                <option value=""></option>
                <option value='12'>Verde</option>
                <option value='8'>Azul</option>
                <option value='6'>Amarillo</option>
                <option value='0'>Rojo</option>
                <option value='-8'>Negro</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select name="puntos" id="puntos" required>
                <option value=""></option>
                <option value='12'>Verde</option>
                <option value='8'>Azul</option>
                <option value='6'>Amarillo</option>
                <option value='0'>Rojo</option>
                <option value='-8'>Negro</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select name="puntos" id="puntos" required>
                <option value=""></option>
                <option value='12'>Verde</option>
                <option value='8'>Azul</option>
                <option value='6'>Amarillo</option>
                <option value='0'>Rojo</option>
                <option value='-8'>Negro</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
            <input name="res" class="res" value=''>
            </td>                           
    </tr>                       
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**Actualización:**
 Modifiqué el evento para que sume solo los valores de su fila sin la necesidad de ids dinamícos. Ahora cada fila tendrá una suma independiente. Saludos.

Comment: @alanfcm. Gracias por responder tan pronto. ¿Lo del **id** se puede solucionar así?: `<select name="puntos<?= $i; ?>" id="puntos<?= $i; ?>" required>` De esta manera el **id** toma el valor de `$i` en cada iteración **puntos1** **puntos2**... Respecto a las filas, mas adelante van a ir varias, según la cantidad de registros de una tabla de MySQL. Los valores del select, también pienso traerlos con una consulta a MySQL. ¿Me pueden indicar por favor cómo le agrego un **id** a cada fila si las voy a pintar con un `while`? Por ejemplo: `<?php while ($row=$query->fetch_array()):?>`

Comment: asi como lo pones es correcto. Aún así actualicé mi respuesta, espero te sirva

Comment: Funciona perfecto. Mil gracias por la ayuda y la disposición Rene.

Answer (score 2):

No puedes usar id para identificar los select porque el id tiene que ser unico en todo el DOM.  Tienes que usar clases.  Ademas el valor debes de inicialiarlo a 0 y agregar todos los valores seleccionados.  Algo asi:

```js
$("table .puntos").change(function(){
  var valor = 0;  
  $("table .puntos").each(function(i, punto) {
    if ($.isNumeric(parseInt($(punto).val()))) {
      valor += parseInt($(punto).val());
    }
  });
  $(this).parents('tr').find(".final").html(valor);     
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th> Lunes </th>
            <th> Martes </th>
            <th> Miercoles </th>
            <th> Jueves </th>
            <th> Viernes </th>
            <th> Puntos Obtenidos </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            
            <td>
                <select class="puntos" required>
                <option value=""></option>
                <option value='12'>Verde</option>
                <option value='8'>Azul</option>
                <option value='6'>Amarillo</option>
                <option value='0'>Rojo</option>
                <option value='-8'>Negro</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select class="puntos" required>
                <option value=""></option>
                <option value='12'>Verde</option>
                <option value='8'>Azul</option>
                <option value='6'>Amarillo</option>
                <option value='0'>Rojo</option>
                <option value='-8'>Negro</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select class="puntos" required>
                <option value=""></option>
                <option value='12'>Verde</option>
                <option value='8'>Azul</option>
                <option value='6'>Amarillo</option>
                <option value='0'>Rojo</option>
                <option value='-8'>Negro</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select class="puntos" required>
                <option value=""></option>
                <option value='12'>Verde</option>
                <option value='8'>Azul</option>
                <option value='6'>Amarillo</option>
                <option value='0'>Rojo</option>
                <option value='-8'>Negro</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select class="puntos" required>
                <option value=""></option>
                <option value='12'>Verde</option>
                <option value='8'>Azul</option>
                <option value='6'>Amarillo</option>
                <option value='0'>Rojo</option>
                <option value='-8'>Negro</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        <td class="final">
            <!-- Aquí iría el código para calcular los puntos -->
        </td>                           
    </tr>                       
  </tbody>
</table>
```